# Why can't my 2D array run?

Tags: java, arrays, output

I have a simple 2D array which is being printed to the screen.

My problem is that the code will not compile properly, what am I doing wrong?

My non working code is:

```
/* This program initialises two-dimensional arrays.......*/

/* ********************************************************/



 public class InitArray4
{
     // create and output two-dimensional arrays
     public static void main( String[] args )
{

int[][] array1 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
int[][] array2 = { { 1, 2 }, { 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };



System.out.println( "Values in array1 by row are" );
outputArray( array1 ); // displays array1 by row

System.out.println( "\nValues in array2 by row are" );
outputArray( array2 ); // displays array2 by row
} // end main

// output rows and columns of a two-dimensional array
 public static void outputArray()
 {
 // loop through array's rows
 for ( int row = 0; row < array.length; row++ )
  {
    // loop through columns of current row
    for ( int column = 0; column < array[ row ].length; column++ )

    System.out.printf( "%d ", array[ row ][ column ] );
    System.out.println(); // start new line of output
  } // end outer for


 } // end method outputArray
} // end class InitArray
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add arguments to your function

```
 public static void outputArray( int[][] array) {
```